# Change Column Name Dynamically Using Mapping Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, mapping

Interesting but sophisticated for me to deal with this requirement, well I have following information:

```
CREATE TABLE #mainTable (id INT, ename VARCHAR(20), eaddress VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #mainTable VALUES
(1, 'A', 'B'),
(2, 'B', 'C'),
(3, 'C', 'D')

--OrgTable
id  ename   eaddress
1   A       B
2   B       C
3   C       D

CREATE TABLE #mappingTable (ExportField VARCHAR(20), SelectField VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #mappingTable VALUES
(1, 'ID'),
(2, 'EName'),
(3, 'EAddress')

--#mappingTable
ExportField     SelectField
1               ID
2               EName
3               EAddress

CREATE TABLE #queryBlock(id INT, Equery VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #queryBlock VALUES 
(1, 'SELECT id AS [ID], ename AS [EName], eaddress AS [EAddress] FROM #mainTable')
```

I just have to execute this query which is saved above in the Equery column where I can't make changes directly but the output will be as below with new column name or header from mapping table.

```
--Desired Output
1   2       3
-------------
1   A       B
2   B       C
3   C       D
```

I have dozens of similar task of mapping but stuck in thinking of where to start from. Please help me on this, Really I will be thank full to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found very simple solution for my question, hope you guys understand what exactly I wanted the solution of my question. Thank you everyone for giving your precious time and still expecting more simpler solution. Again, I want feedback on this solution. Sorry @Shnugo your code really not working and still expecting solution, I have tested http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler and getting same issue as mentioned in comment:

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sqlQuery = Equery FROM #queryBlock WHERE id = 1
SELECT @sqlQuery = REPLACE(@sqlQuery, '['+SelectField+']', '['+ExportField+']') 
FROM #mappingTable

EXEC(@sqlQuery)
```

Comment: If your queries in `#queryBlock` are 1) that simple and 2) you can be sure, that the replace will never change other unwanted parts, this is simple and OK. I would never use this solution productively, it's just to dangerous and prone for future problems... It is easy to build the whole statement *on-the-fly* (see my updated answer and sorry for the mistake there), but it can be a hell to re-do an existing more complex query...

Comment: Your query is working fine now +1 for that and my #queryBlock always holds query in same format though can hold with some complex joins. Yes, if there we find any other same text in the same format as alias then it creates serious problem so we can only go with this simpler answer by holding certain things on mind. Happy to get back to your query again :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the below query.

```
DECLARE@colList varchar(500)

SELECT @colList=coalesce(@colList+ ',', '') +  convert(varchar(12),SelectField)+' as '+QUOTENAME(cast(ExportField as varchar(10))) 
FROM #mappingTable B

INSERT INTO #queryBlock VALUES 
(1, 'SELECT '+ @colList+'FROM #mainTable')
```

If you wanted to execute it dynamically,try to script like below.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT '+ @colList+'FROM #mainTable'
EXEC(@sql)
```

If you wanted to run it from #queryblock tabble ,use the below script.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql=Equery FROM #queryBlock WHERE ID=1
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: ExportField and ID column of main table value not always same in my sample it looks like but in real it it different because one is serial number of data and another is, I would say column-alias.

Comment: Upto colList it's working fine but what i need after that is to execute the complete query with columns what you have in colList.

Comment: Hi, just one hint: Better use `QOUTENAME()` then building this yourself with `' as [' +  xyz + ']'` And it would be better to do the same with the `SelectField`. We don't know, if there might be column names with blanks...

Comment: Exactly what I want +1 for that :) but why we are using defining select and from clause again though we have in the equery column of #queryBlock table. Can you please provide the solution in that way.

Comment: @UnnikrishnanR One thing I want to say is why we are again inserting manipulated query again in #queryBlock, where as this is my physical table and not allowed to insert/update in the table. Can't we perform this without doing that ?

Comment: Am not getting you..we are inserting the querystring in to #queryBlock only once.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have to set a column's name dynamically you have to use dynamic SQL:

Btw: I'm quite sure, that the structure you showed us will not cover your needs...

```
CREATE TABLE #mainTable (id INT, ename VARCHAR(20), eaddress VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #mainTable VALUES
(1, 'A', 'B'),
(2, 'B', 'C'),
(3, 'C', 'D')


CREATE TABLE #mappingTable (ExportField VARCHAR(20), SelectField VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #mappingTable VALUES
(1, 'ID'),
(2, 'EName'),
(3, 'EAddress')

DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100)='#mainTable'; -- shouldn't this be configured in #mappingTable

DECLARE @statement VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT 'SELECT ' + STUFF(
                       (
                        SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(SelectField) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(ExportField)
                        FROM #mappingTable
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ),1,1,'' 
                       )
         + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)
)

PRINT @statement; 

--execute this
EXEC(@statement);
GO

DROP TABLE #mappingTable
DROP TABLE #mainTable
```

The created statement

```
SELECT [ID] AS [1],[EName] AS [2],[EAddress] AS [3] FROM [#mainTable]
```

Comment: exactly, I have clearly mentioned that ExportField as column header which will replace column alias of stored query. But I can't change the one stored query.

Comment: @Suraz, so will it work to create the statement entirely or do you have more complex statements where you want to change just some parts (which was much more difficult!)

Comment: Look my final statement will be as 'SELECT id AS [1],ename AS [2],eaddress AS [3] FROM #mainTable' which will provide me my desired output. I have quite similar requirement and format also same.

Comment: @Suraz, well, my query does exactly this... Doesn't it?

Comment: Getting this issue: Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 18
The name 'SELECT [ID] AS [1],[EName] AS [2],[EAddress] AS [3] FROM [#mainTable]' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @Suraz, please show what you've tried... This statement should work... Is your standard collation case sensitive?

Comment: I have used whole of your code and my standard collation case is in-sensitive.

Comment: @Suraz, sorry, silly me... `EXEC` needs the statement in paranthesis... Edited my answer... You might check it [here on SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a41bc/3)